# Checkbox's labels are not vertically aligned when added programmatically

Tags: android, label, center, vertical-alignment, android-checkbox

I want to align vertically the `CheckBox` and their text/labels.

I add checkbox programmatically like this:

```
private LinearLayout ProposalLayout;
ProposalLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_proposals);
this.ProposalLayout = ProposalLayout;

Iterator<Proposal> iter = q.getListProposals().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Proposal p = iter.next();
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(activity);
    cb.setText(p.getProposal());
    cb.setId(p.getId());
    ProposalLayout.addView(cb);
}
```

Here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_proposals"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="New CheckBox"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:text="New CheckBox"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The `CheckBox` added in the layout are good. The first one added programmatically is great but the others are not vertically aligned (their labels).

EDIT: 
It's perfectly aligned when I replace:

```
cb.setText(p.getProposal());
```

by:

```
cb.setText("test test test");
```

The problem was in the XML file, there was a line break, I just didn't see it in the logs.

Comment: What do you mean by "not vertically aligned (their labels)"? What alignment do you need?

Comment: I mean the checkbox aligned with label, on the same line.

Comment: Ohh, I thought you mean to align to left, center or right. Could you add a screenshot of unaligned checkbox? And what is wrong with `getProposal()` method? Please provide it's source code.

Comment: Or example of text returned by `Proposal.getProposal()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define layout params for your checkbox and then set them as parameter. First the layout params:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,     
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
```

Then add the view:

```
ProposalLayout.addView(cb, params);
```

Comment: Just did it but labels are still not aligned.

Comment: Ok, then try cb.setGravity(CENTER_VERTICAL) in your iterator code.

Comment: If you need to align label to left then replace `Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL` with `Gravity.LEFT`.

Comment: Is there in line break in "p.getProposal()"?

Comment: @ThomasR. No, I thought this too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

set the height of the both `CheckBox`s to `wrap_content` in XML

```
android:layout_height="70dp"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: These two `CheckBox` are here for testing only. They are correctly displayed and their labels are vertically aligned. I want to align the ones added programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use solution suggested by Thomas R. It should work. Or you can try mine:

```
...
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    ...
    cb.setParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,     
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    ...
}
```

And add

```
<LinearLayout
     ...
    android:gravity="left">
```

Comment: The solution suggested by Thomas R. doesn't work and yours either unfortunately.